# DateTime.TryParseExact single second

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I have time results from races in many different formats (more or less any combination of hour, minute, second and millisecond):

- 01:22:51.15
- 22:15.12
- 15.0
- 12:21
- ...

I parse them with a list of valid formats and so far all the formats work except one: The single second format, e.g. "5".

For some reason the following list (containing "s" as the 1st item) does not help me to parse the string "5" into a DateTime, "25" works fine though.

```
var timeString = "5";
var timeFormats = new[] { "s", "s.f", "s.ff", "ss", "ss.f", "ss.ff", "m:ss", "m:ss.f", "m:ss.ff", "mm:ss", "mm:ss.f", "mm:ss.ff", "H:mm:ss", "H:mm:ss.f", "H:mm:ss.ff", "HH:mm:ss", "HH:mm:ss.f", "HH:mm:ss.ff" };
DateTime timeValue;
DateTime.TryParseExact(timeString, timeFormats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out timeValue);
```

Any idea why this does not work as I expect it to? Or is there a cleaner way to cover all these time formats without adding another nuget package...?
Cheers!

Comment: I don't suppose it's too much to ask for what that code is currently giving you? "This doesn't work" isn't much to go on.

Comment: You're working with time spans. That's what `TimeSpan` is for, not `DateTime`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that TryParseExact does return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is only one character in the format, it is being treated as [the Sortable standard format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable), rather than as a custom format with seconds.

To change this, prefix the custom format with a `%` character, as in `"%s"`.  See ["Using single custom format specifiers"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers).

Also, recognize that if these are actual elapsed times of races, `TimeSpan` is a more appropriate data structure than `DateTime`.  Be careful when switching, as not all formatting tokens are identical between the two objects.  In particular, `TimeSpan` uses `h` for hours, not `H`.  See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee372287.aspx).

Comment: The %s did the trick, thank you. I'm aware of TimeSpan, but I have to store it in the database as DateTime and therefor was parsing it into a DateTime.

Comment: You shouldn't store it as a DateTime in the database.  Instead, store as a number of total seconds, or total milliseconds, or whatever precision you need.  Storing as a DateTime is using the wrong type, and could lead to errors down the road.